# What is the benefit by using ASP.NET MVC if I have already done webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have already learned asp .net webform and have created projects for college on it but I recently discovered asp.net MVC.
I tried to learn it but it seems way to different in terms of how you build the application and there's a steeper learning curve.

If I have already done asp.net, do I need to learn MVC as well taking in account the future real life projects I might have to do?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a good question (subjective) and it has been asked many times (just look at the related questions on this page alone). Yes, MS MVC is much different than web forms but ultimately it represents a cleaner model because of the virtues of the MVC pattern itself, the amount of effort MS has put into their MVC framework, and the benefit of hindsight (the core web forms paradigm is over 12 years old).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build any web application using the asp forms.

MVC is great, you don't need to learn it, but if you do you will enjoy it much better than web forms because it is much closer to how web works. I believe that in few years it will be more popular than regular ASP forms.

MVC with Razor gives you more control on the rendered HTML, but on the downside if you don't know HTML and CSS then it is easier to just drop the ASP controls.

One other advantage of the MVC 4, is adding the web API services. Learning MVC is a must to know how to write these useful services.

Comment: ...And both Razor and web API can be used in asp.net web forms. You don't have to learn MVC to write asp.net web API

Comment: They do share many things, like routes, filters ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Well explained pros of mvc on below link

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview